# Facebook SDK FB.API post screenshot with user's message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to post a screenshot and upload it to the user's facebook account. I'm working with unity (c#) and using facebook SDK and it's working fine with the example code i got from their Docs.

I even managed to "pre-fill" a message and post it with the screenshot. But pre-filling a message is against [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) [exanples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGz48L0m5nc), so i'm looking for a way to use the same method and let the user fill in a message while i don't break Facebook Platform Policy.

here is the working code i used:

```
     private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
     {
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

         var width = Screen.width;
         var height = Screen.height;
         var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
         // Read screen contents into the texture
         tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
         tex.Apply();
         byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

         var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
         wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");
         wwwForm.AddField("message","some message"); // violating Facebook Platform Policy
         FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `InputField` and `Button` components comes into play. Get user message with `InputField` and send when Button is clicked. You can hide both the `InputField` and send `Button` before taking screenshot.

```
public InputField userInput;
public Button postButton;


public void OnEnable()
{
    postButton.onClick.AddListener(postToFB);
}

void postToFB()
{
    Debug.Log("Posting To FB");
    StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshot(userInput.text));
}

private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot(string textToPost)
{
    //Hide User Input
    userInput.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    //Hide Send Button
    postButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");
    wwwForm.AddField("message", textToPost);
    FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);
}

public void OnDisable()
{
    postButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: I remember that i read somewhere that custom inputs are not allowed as well by facebook's platform policy. I cant find it now though

Comment: @Sag1v What are you talking about? You should NOT refill the input. You let the user type of whatever they want.  That's what the code above does and there is no facebook policy that  says it is bad. Assuming you modified `userInput.text` instead of using what the user typed in, then that is not ok.

Comment: @Sag1v "You may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but don't prefill any content a person didn't create via the API" The text has to be created by the user not you. Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGz48L0m5nc  The code in my answer is ok. The one in your question is not. Prefill is when you modify the content user typed in before or after posting it.

Comment: Im not saying you used prefill but i remember something about we cant use custom inputs instead of facebook's dialog... trying to find it

Comment: well i can't find it but i think you are right here about the ability to make our own Share-UI. as i can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/sharing ( API based sharing). anyway thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Sag1v Ok. Just read the link you provided. Don't forget to name the text on your button "Share" according to facebook.  Everything else should be fine. Happy coding!